# Finding the probability using a tree.

Tags: probability, trees

Let's say a specific exam has 3 levels (I, II, III). The candidates who pass the first exam are then eligible to take the next level of the exam. Let's say the pass rates for levels I, II, and III are .57, .73, and .85 respectively. Supposed 3000 people took level I, 2500 took level II, and 2000 took level III. Supposed one student is selected and he says he passed the exam. What is the probability that he took the level I exam? I tried drawing a tree to list out all the possibilities but I still don't know what the question is asking.

Here's what my tree looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiGxe.png

Comment: What does your tree look like?

Comment: This question is unclear. Doesn't everyone have to take the first level to pass the exam?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_n$ be the event that the student took the Level $n$ exam.   You know how many students took each so *assuming there is no bias* in selecting the student from among the examinees...

$$~\mathsf P(E_{\rm I})~=\\ \mathsf P(E_{\rm II})~=\\ \mathsf P(E_{\rm III})~=$$

Let $S$ be the event that the student passed the exam.   You've been given the values of the conditional probabilies of passing a given exam: $$~\mathsf P(S\mid E_{\rm I})~=~0.57\\ \mathsf P(S\mid E_{\rm II})~=~0.73 \\ \mathsf P(S\mid E_{\rm III})~=~0.85~$$

You are looking to find the conditional probability of taking an exam given that the exam taken was passed.   Use the above to calculate this. $$\mathsf P(E_{\rm I}\mid S)~=$$

Fill in the blanks.

Comment: Does the amount of people taking each exam have something to do with finding P(E1∣S)

Comment: I still don't understand how this question works. Here's the tree that I drew: http://i.imgur.com/tSyfHJW.png So using this tree, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Chase Indeed not.  The tree should have three main branches (one for each test) with each forking into two child branches (pass or fail) leading to six leaf nodes (pass Level I, fail Level I, pass Level II, fail Level II, pass Level III, fail Level III).  Given that the student is on one of the three "pass" nodes, what is the probability that it is the "pass Level I" node.

Comment: The statement "The candidates who pass the first exam are then eligible to take the next level of the exam." is a distraction.  The given amounts of people taking each exam are those taking one *now*.  If they pass they qualify to take the next Level *later*.

Comment: So then it's a given question. Which is P(E and S)/P(E). I know what P(E) is (I assume it's 3000/7500) but what about P(E and S). I would I find that out. You said there should be 6 leaf nodes but what I drew was the 3 levels and each level consisting of a pass or fail and if you pass the level then you can do the next level.